# How to include chemfig figures (LaTeX package) in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, latex

I am currently in the state of learning `matplotlib.pyplot`, and it would be nice to have `LaTeX` integration to work as flawlessly as possible.

This is what I currently have:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Latex implementation
plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rc('text.latex', preamble=r'\usepackage{chemfig},\usepackage{siunitx}')

# import data from file
with open ('vanillin.dat') as dat:
    lines = dat.readlines()
    wavenumbers = [float(line.split()[0]) for line in lines]
    absorption = [float(line.split()[1]) for line in lines]


# axis labels and plot title
plt.title("IR Spectrum of Vanillin", fontsize=22)

plt.xlabel('Wavenumber in cm$^{-1}$', fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel('Absorption in \%', fontsize=16)


# axis limits (Wavenumber on x coordinate has to be reversed)
plt.ylim(0,100)
plt.xlim(4000,600)

# grid and plot drawing
plt.grid(color='gray', linestyle=':')

plt.plot(wavenumbers, absorption, c='black', linewidth=0.5)

# save plot
plt.savefig('output.png')
```

The code above results in the following spectrum:

[image: Plain plot]

Now, if I want to add text (which includes macros from an included `LaTeX` package, namely `siunitx`), this works perfectly. This is the added line (added below `plt.ylabel()`), and below the resulting plot:

```
plt.text(3700, 80, r'Peak at \SI{1600}{\per\centi\meter} $\rightarrow$ carbonyl', fontsize=12)
```

[image: Plot with added text using]

Now, I want to include the structure for vanillin, which is generated by the `chemfig` code below:

```
\chemfig{*6((-HO)=(-O-[:-30])-=(-=[2]O)-=-)}
```

This is what it looks like:

[image: Chemical structure of vanillin]

If I now include the code into my plot, it is somehow not possible to display it correctly:

```
plt.text(3300, 80, r'\chemfig{*6((-HO)=(-O-[:-30])-=(-=[2]O)-=-)}')
```

[image: plot with chemfig structure which is not displayed correctly]

Anyone have an idea on how to fix this issue?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: That's not going to work. The latex you are trying to include consists of much more than text, so matplotlib doesn't know how to render that. You could produce the molecular structure in latex, export as image and include that image in the figure. You could also export your matplotlib figure, import it in latex and place the molecule in latex on top of the figure.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I see... in this case, it will probably be easier for me to include it directly in LaTeX. Thanks!

Comment: As a side note, I'd suggest not to use raster graphics whenever possible and export to PDF instead of PNG.

Comment: @andselisk sure. It's just easier to directly export to png in order to upload to imgur than to pdf and converting with `imagemagick` afterwards.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Does the output change if you put the complete \chemfig stuff in a `\parbox` as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155699/how-to-use-display-equations-with-psfrag) for a totally different case though?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest the line `plt.text(3300, 80, r'\parbox{3cm}{\chemfig{*6((-HO)=(-O-[:-30])-=(-=[2]O)-=-)}}')` does not change anything in the resulting spectrum.

Comment: Ok, thanks for sharing. I was thinking that if the positions of the letters (O, H) were changed by that, there would still be a chance... but if nothing changes, the first comment stays valid.